# `pip install pyside` freezes on Linux?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

Here's the terminal output:

```
alien@alien-linux:~$ pip install pyside
Collecting pyside
  Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyside
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyside
```

Nothing seems to happen beyond where I have just gotten to, and I have tried waiting for a good 20-25 minutes. Any ideas why this might be the case?

According to the answers to this question, the recommended way for installing pyside on Ubuntu is [through the official repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845709/recommended-way-for-installing-pyside-on-ubuntu), but if I do that, I get `ImportError` (no module found) if I try something like `import pyside`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Waiting 20-25min might not suffice; it's possibly downloading and compiling Qt in the background, which is an enormous project.

You should definitely not install `pyside` via pip if you can help it at all.

> I get ImportError (no module found) if I try something like import pyside.

No surprise here:

it's `import PySide`, not `pyside`.

Comment: Thank you. I installed PySide instead from the Anaconda repositories (where I suppose they have a lot of the dependencies prebuilt).